# не отображается картинка primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Мне нужно отобразить картинку на странице. Но сама картинка находится в byte[].
Не отображается картинка. Подскажите пожалуйста, что я упустил?
вот такой графикИмидж

```
<p:graphicImage value="#{profileBean.photo2}" library="images" width="110" height="150" id="photo" />
```

вот такой вот бин:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ProfileBean implements Serializable{
    ...
    private byte[] photo;
    private StreamedContent photo2;

    public ProfileBean() {
        UserBean currentUser;
        photo = currentUser.getPhoto();
        InputStream iStream = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream("/resources/images/somePhoto.png");

        photo2 = new DefaultStreamedContent(iStream, "image/png");

        } 
    public StreamedContent getPhoto2() {
        return photo2;
    }

    public void setPhoto2(StreamedContent photo2) {
        this.photo2 = photo2;
    }

}
```

В принципе, из byte[] получить `InputStream` не сложно, но хоть так чтобы завелось, когда я ему скармливаю конкретную картинку из ресурсов..

Comment: Интересно.. если поменять ViewScoped на SessionScoped - тогда все отрабатывает.

Comment: но надо все-таки чтобы работало на ViewScoped бине

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас не получится возвращать изображение из компонента с уровнем видимости `ViewScoped`. Это связано со спецификой отрисовки изображений браузером и спецификой работы JSF с состояниями отображений (View-s). При получении страницы браузером с сервера, он сначала отрисовывает тег img, но не само изображение. Чтобы получить изображение, браузер выполняет отдельный запрос к серверу, но не передаёт при этом состояние (`ViewState`), поэтому сервер в ответ на запрос формирует полностью новый `View`, в котором и создаётся `StreamedContent`. В связи с тем, что это два разных `View`, изображение не попадает туда, где вы его ожидаете.

Если *"но надо все-таки чтобы работало на ViewScoped бине"* - это окончательное решение, то у вас вряд ли получится заставить это работать в текущем виде. Скорее всего, придётся заменить `p:graphicImage` на `h:graphicImage` и получать изображение из сервлета примерно так:

```
<h:graphicImage value="/userPhotoServlet?userId=#{profileBean.userId}" width="110" height="150"/>
```

Как разработать такой сервлет выходит за рамки вопроса, но это не сложно. Если всё же есть возможность сменить область видимости - то кроме `SessionScoped`, это будет работать также и в `RequestScoped`.

**PS** Мое личное мнение по поводу `ViewScoped` таково: это вещь настолько хрупкая и подверженная очень неочевидным и труднорешаемым проблемам, что я стараюсь не использовать её вообще, несмотря на удобство такого уровня видимости.

Comment: спасибо. все-таки пришлось сменить область видимости, иначе, да, не решается. Но я сменил область видимости только этого атрибута, т.е. сам бин остался ViewScoped, но в xhtml для получения фотки обращаюсь не к этому,ViewScoped бину, а к SessionScoped бину, где уже и лежит фотография юзера..