# fileUpload и graphicImage

Tags: jsf, primefaces

в продолжение [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/494244/%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0-primefaces/494468#494468). На странице имеется компонент fileUpload Primefaces и оттуда же graphicImage. Когда в первый раз открываешь страницу, картинка показывается правильно, если же выбрать новый файл картинки (использовать fileUpload), на странице она не обновляется, но если обновить страницу (F5) - покажется правильная картинка, та, которую выбрал.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем я ошибся.
вот кусок кода xhtml:

```
<h:form class="main_form" id="main_form">
      <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="fileUploadForm">
          <div  class="user_photo">
              <div>
                  <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{profileBeanViewScoped.handleFileUpload}" 
                       mode="advanced" auto="true"
                       label="Выбрать"  
                       sizeLimit="1024000" 
                       allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(jpe?g|png)$/" 
                       update="photo"/>                         
               </div>
               <div>
                    <p:graphicImage value="#{userBeanSessionScoped.streamedPhoto}" width="110" height="150" id="photo" />
               </div>

         </div>
     </h:form>
</h:form>
```

Процедура загрузки файла

```
    public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    photoFile = event.getFile();
    photo = photoFile.getContents();
    UserBean.getInstance().setUpdatedPhoto(photoFile);
}
```

и процедура, которая вернет картинку

```
    public StreamedContent getStreamedPhoto() {

    if (UserBean.getInstance().getUpdatedPhoto() != null) {
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(UserBean.getInstance().getUpdatedPhoto());
        return new DefaultStreamedContent(bis);
    } else {
        // пойдем в базу данных и дернем оттуда фотографию юзера по его айди
        return new DefaultStreamedContent(UserBean.getInstance().loadUserPhotoFromDB());
    }

}
```

При отладке вижу, что в картинку возвращается правильный StreamedContent, но graphicImage мой все равно не обновляется, чего то я не знаю...

Comment: 1. Вложенные формы запрещены в HTML, соответственно, и в JSF тоже.
2. То, что при отладке вы видите правильный StreamedContent в вашем серверном компоненте, ещё не значит, что он попал в нужный JSF View. В разрезе предыдущего вопроса, попробуйте опять сменить уровень видимости на SessionScoped.

Comment: с формой понял, спасибо, но как бы я не менял видимость, пока результат тот же, увы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p:graphicImage` по умолчанию кеширует изображение. Это можно увидеть в отладчике браузера, при загрузке изображения и попытке обновить `p:graphicImage` там появляется запись вида:

```
cb64db6a-f02e-442b-ac39-3565c1e9aa57    200 jpeg    Other   (from cache)
```

Обратите внимание на `(from cache)`. Если указать для `p:graphicImage` свойство cache="false", то добавится ещё один запрос вида:

```
dynamiccontent.properties.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=5.3&pfdrid=S94%2BwOgIhsFiqTI7qBMqxj1Nau3qavPSBOOG6AMfVc6TYh8gS9ReMA%3D%3D&pfdrt=sc&pfdrid_c=false&uid=21bcf634-37b2-4519-a59f-085a8b0416ba  200 jpeg    Other   132 KB
```

Изображение на странице при этом обновится.

Comment: огромное спасибо.
от себя также добавлю: удалось только если связать файл аплоадер и график имидж с SessionScoped бином. я сделал отдельный бин с одним свойством - массив байтов: который содержит фотографию, собственно, отсюда и плясал далее.